# How to connect google-cloud-firestore to swift?

Tags: node.js, swift, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I was unable to connect Firestore-cloud to xcode using Firestore-CLI, but was unable  to do so.

So, Now, I am trying to connect Firestore to serverless - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions ,  which in console is -
https://console.cloud.google.com .

I  have the following functions -

1). the function in the given example is - "helloWorld" , the code is -

```
      exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
      let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
      res.status(200).send(message);
       };
```

-- It gets deployed as -  https://*myregion*-testpro-92351.cloudfunctions.net/function-1

2). I have also tested another function  "helloHttp", the code is -

```
      exports.helloHttp = (req, res) => {
      res.send(`Hello ${escapeHtml(req.query.name || req.body.name || 'World')}!`);
       };
```

-- It gets deployed as - https://*myregion*-testpro-92351.cloudfunctions.net/function-5

The above functions gets deployed successfully.

Also, my swift Viewcontroller code is -

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    class TestViewController:
    UIViewController {
    @IBAction func Test(_ sender: Any) {  } }
```

The package.json for both the above functions is -

```
       {
      "name": "sample-http",
       "version": "0.0.1"
        }
```

I have the following question -

What should I put inside the button - "@IBAction func Test(_ sender: Any) {  } }" in "TestViewController" above to make both functions, 1). "function-1", i.e. "helloWorld" and 2). "function-5", i.e. "helloHttp" print "HelloWorld" in xcode console.

Comment: You have at least two completely separate questions here. You should consider narrowing the focus so that they can be answered individually.

Comment: Okay, then I am most concered about the ii)nd point.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to reflect that. Include what you've tried so far. There's a section in the documentation about how to do it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: Did you try the code that is in the documentation for calling a function from Swift? Where did you run into an issue?

Comment: @jnpdx -  The link which you pointed out -  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable - deals with Firebase Database and not Cloud firestore.  Furthermore, it is most probably through CLI. I have not used CLI but used - https://console.cloud.google.com/ , the notes for which is most probably - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions . I just want to connect my swift i.e. TestViewController to a deployed function.

Comment: The link I pointed to is not for "Firebase database" it is for "Cloud Functions". In your question, you specifically linked to a Firestore document about "Extend with functions" which are cloud functions. And, no, the link I provided is not specifically about doing this through a CLI. It specifically has a section about calling from Swift, which would work in an app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function

Comment: Please click on the "CommentCell.swift"(routes you to the Github post/link) in the link (firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) provided by @jnpdx. I think its exactly what you are looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this not too long ago, to deploy functions for your app's functionality, deploy them from terminal.

To execute a function and/or pass in parameters, from within your app, you can use AlamoFire. Each function has it's own URL which AlamoFire can retrieve and from there on you may wish to pass through whatever data is needed.

Comment: What would the advantage of Alamofire be in this situation vs. the built in URLSession?

Comment: Please see the first line of my question, I am unable to do it through CLI